# Alternate of like in oracle select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with single column.
 TABLE T with data like:

```
 A11
B1
As112
DF123
VG112
```

I'm lookingfor alternate of like (VG% and DF%) ... Because i think if there will be more to compare it may effect performance

Comment: Alternate would be `exact` match. And if you dont know exact match then there is no go. You have to use like operator.

Comment: Please post your trial query and the excpected result

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the alternatives you could try. Performance may improve if you have function based index specific to these expressions in where clause (`substr`).

```
select * FROM t where SUBSTR(data,1,2) = 'VG'; -- If you are always comparing first 2 characters.

select * FROM t where SUBSTR(data,1,2) IN (  'VG' , 'DF');  -- Multiple comparisions
```

`INSTR` is another option but you cannot have an index which suits this comparison.

```
select * FROM t where INSTR(data,'VG') = 1;
```

Comment: @steve The answer here doesnot give an alternate to your question. `like (VG% and DF%)` is not same as `SUBSTR(data,1,2) IN (  'VG' , 'DF');`

Answer (score 0):

I think that `like` is the best choice. You can create list of patterns and use join, like here:

```
select * from t join p on t.text like p.pattern||'%'
```

It does not matter if you use built-in type `odcivarchar2list` or define patterns using `union all`, it only makes syntax shorter.

Example:

```
with t(text) as (
    select column_value 
      from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A11', 'B1', 'As112', 'DF123', 'VG112'))),
p(pattern) as (
    select column_value 
      from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('DF', 'VG')))
select * 
  from t join p on t.text like p.pattern||'%' 

TEXT    PATTERN
------  -------
DF123   DF
VG112   VG
```